Justification of the Risk Neutral Measure in the Schwartz One Factor Commodity Model
I have been trying to understand the form of the risk neutral measure in the Schwartz one factor model for commodities (Model 1 on page 6 here) where the spot price of a commodity follows the process below  ($Z_t$ a standard brownian motion):
$$dS_t = S_t(\kappa(\mu-ln(S_t))dt+S_t \sigma dZ_t$$
Ito's lemma then implies that $X_t=ln(S_t)$ has the dynamics of an Ornstein Uhlenbeck process
$$dX_t=\kappa (\alpha - X_t)dt + \sigma dZ_t$$
Where $\alpha = \mu - \sigma^2 / 2 \kappa$.
The paper then goes on to take $\lambda$ constant as market risk premium meaning that under a risk neutral measure the process $X_t$ has dynamics ($Z^*_t$ being a standard brownian motion under the risk neutral measure):
$$dX_t=\kappa ((\alpha - \lambda) - X_t)dt + \sigma dZ_t^*$$
The footnote (page 6, footnote 8) linked to this assumption states that in general they would expect the market price of risk to be linked to the business cycle and correlated to inventory levels but without any further detail.
My questions stems applying from the application of the argument in Gibson and Schwartz (1990) (Link, unfortunately only a preview) to the one factor model. I can provide more details of my process (which is based on the approach in Brennan and Schwartz link as cited in Gibson and Schwartz). The main idea is to consider an arbitrary derivative and to construct a risk free portfolio using another derivative to obtain a market price of risk which is consistent between all derivatives.
In the interest of brevity (happy to provide more details if helpful), I believe this culminates in the following pricing PDE for an arbitrary derivative $V(S, t)$, subject to appropriate boundary conditions:
$$\frac{\partial V}{\partial t} + \frac{\partial V}{\partial S}(\mu_S - \lambda(S_t, t) \sigma_S) + \frac{\partial^2 V}{\partial S^2} \frac{\sigma_S^2}{2} - Vr=0$$
With $\mu_S = S_t\kappa(\mu-ln(S_t))$ and $\sigma = S_t \sigma$.
While we may not be able to trade the spot price of the commodity directly, an investor can hold a unit of the commodity in inventory. In this case, the value of this position would simply be $V(S, t) = S$, and after computing the corresponding derivatives the PDE becomes:
$$(0) + (1)(\mu_S - \lambda(S_t, t) \sigma_S) + (0) \frac{\sigma_S^2}{2} - (S)r=0$$
$$(S\kappa(\mu-ln(S))) - \lambda(S, t) (S \sigma) - Sr=0$$
$$\lambda(S, t) = \frac{\kappa(\mu-ln(S)) - r}{\sigma}$$
As is expected, with this choice of $\lambda(S, t)$ the spot price of the underlying $S_t$ grows on average at the risk free rate $r$ under the risk neutral measure.
This model has been discussed on this forum a few times (for example: here, here and here) but I have yet to find an answer that addresses the following questions directly. I believe I am missing a key concept / intuition about this and so apologies if I missed it in other sources.
Questions:

Why can a constant be used as the market price of risk? What justifies this choice?
How do we know that the resulting model with a constant market price of risk is arbitrage free if the risk neutral price process of $S_t$ does not grow at the risk free rate?
Are there any sources that discuss the choice of the market price of risk for commodities in greater detail?

